# How do I insert a key value pair at a specific point in a key/value array in jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hope someone can help in jquery if I have a key value array object

```
    var myArray= {};
    myArray['key1'] = 'value1';
    myArray['key2'] = 'value2';
    myArray['key3'] = 'value3';
    myArray['key5'] = 'value5';
    myArray['key6'] = 'value6';
```

how would I insert another key value pair at a specific point?
e.g. 
    myArray['key4'] = 'value4';
between (or after) key2 and (or before) key3?

Thank you

Comment: This is not an array, it's an object. In Javascript you can access object members with the same syntax as array values (using the square brackets), but it does not make an object and an array the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

There is no guaranteed order in ECMAscript *Objects*, hence, there is no way to insert a new *key/value* pair at a certain point.

Use an *Array* instead.

```
var arr = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5', 'value6'];

arr.splice(2, 0, 'new value');

console.log( arr ); // ['value1', 'value2', 'new value' 'value3', 'value4', 'value5', 'value6'];
```

Comment: Should be `arr.splice(2, 0, 'new value');` since you don't want to remove any of the existing elements.

Comment: It should be stressed that the properties of an array are not ordered either, since arrays are objects. However, they are usually **read** in order using a for (or while or do) loop. Using `splice` changes the names of the properties with an index equal to, or higher than, the index of the new property.

Comment: @RobG: whats the difference ? As you correctly mentioned, any loop including functional-loops reads the *index* property names correctly and will loop in order.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is an object (`{}`), not an array (`[]`). Keys in objects don't have a guaranteed ordering, so you can't insert one at a specific point; they're just properties of that object.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the input. I was hoping their was an equivalent to splice for objects that I had missed. Obviously not so I resorted to good old map and rebuild.

```
function objectInsertafterkey(object, newKey, newVal, insertAfterkey){
newObject={};
$.map(object, function(value, key) {    
if(key == insertAfterkey){
newObject[key] = value;
newObject[newKey] = newVal;
}
else
{
newObject[key] = value;
}
});
return newObject;
}
```

If their is a better way to insert into objects feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

do like this,use object:

```
 var myArray = {key1: value1, key2: value2};
```

add new:

```
myArray.key3 = "value3";
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

the arr.splice will add a new value to existing array

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Answer (score -1):

As jAndy says, if you want a specific order, use arrays.

Alternatively, you can sort the keys before use if they have sortable names (like in your example).